# Get the custom HTTP Status message with Retrofit 2

Tags: android, node.js, api, retrofit

My API return this :

Status : 500, message : Username already taken

This is not the problem because this is what I want.

The probleme is when I want get the message retrofit give me the generic message for this status

This is my code for the request :

```
createUser.enqueue(new Callback<Response>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(retrofit.Response<Response> response, Retrofit retrofit)
            {
                if(response.code() == 500)
                {
                    Log.d("Status message", response.message());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t)
            {
                Log.d("Failure", t.getMessage());
            }
        });
```

Why the Status message is still "Internal Server Error" ?

Comment: cause 500 is the "internal server error" by default

Comment: And how can I change it for my custom message ?

Comment: Your error should be returned in onFailure and onResponse transmit only positive